# Setting values of an array to -inf in Python with scipy/numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have an array that looks like this:

```
a = [ -22  347 4448  294  835 4439  587  326]
```

I want to set its 0 or smaller values to -inf. I tried the following:

```
a[where(a <= 0)] = -inf
```

when I do this, I get the error:

```
OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
```

Any idea why this is and how I can fix it? the "where" function should return the indices of values less than or equal to 0, and the assignment should just set those values to -inf.  thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your array `a` is an array of integers.  Integers can't represent infinity -- only floating point numbers can.  So there are to fixes:

1. Use an array of floating point numbers instead.
2. Use a large negative integer value, e.g. `-2147483648` if you are using 32-bit integers.  Of course that's not the same as -infinity, but in some contexts it behaves similar.

Furthermore, you can simply write

```
a[a <= 0] = <somevalue>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your array's type is integer, you won't be able to set any values to `-infinity`. That's a special value in IEEE floating point.  The obvious way to fix it is to use an array of floats.